# HBase Data Access performance improvement using HBase API

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I am trying to scan some rows using prefix filter from the HBase table. I am on HBase 0.96.

I want to increase the throughput of each RPC call so as to reduce the number of request hitting the region.

I tried getCaching(int) and setCacheBlocks(true) on the scan object. I also tried adding resultScanner.next(int). Using all these combination I am still not able to reduce the number of RPC calls. I am still hitting HBase region for each key instead of bringing the multiple keys per RPC call.

The HBase region server/ Datanode has enough CPU and Memory allocated. Also my data is evenly distributed across different region servers. Also the data that I am bring back per key is not a lot.

I observed that when I add more data to the table the time taken for the request increases. It also increases when the number of request increases.

Thank you for your help.

R

Comment: can you show u some code? prefix filter in particular

Comment: Here is the partialfilter                                                                 ArrayList<Filter> filters = new ArrayList<Filter>();
            
            for(String flag : periodFlags) {
                byte[] prefix = Bytes.toBytes(key1 + "_" + key2 + "_");
                filters.add(new PrefixFilter(prefix));
            }
            
            FilterList filterList = new FilterList(FilterList.Operator.MUST_PASS_ONE, filters);
            Scan criteria = new Scan(Bytes.toBytes(key1 + "_"));
            criteria.setFilter(filterList);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prefix filter is usually a performance killer because they perform full table scan, always use a start and stop row in your scans rather than prefix filter.

```
Scan scan = new Scan(Bytes.toBytes("prefix"),Bytes.toBytes("prefix~"));
```

when iterate over the `Result` from the `ResultScanner`, every iteration is an RPC call, you can call `resultScanner.next(n)` to get a batch of results in one go.

Comment: I understand prefix filter is a performance killer but I don't have the full key information upfront. So I cannot use this. Is there a start and stop with prefix filter? Thanks

Comment: what I wrote is essentially a prefix filter

Comment: Let me try and see. Thanks

Comment: @user3771144 the start row doesn't need to be exact

Comment: I tested the ideas that you gave, the number of requests did not reduce. Also I am looking at getting the request times down. What I am observing is as the number of concurrent requests increases the time taken increases. It also increases as the size of table grows? Is there a way I can reduce this as well.

Comment: It did improve a little but like I said as the number of concurrent requests increases the time taken increases. It also increases as the size of table grows?